# Extracting domains and IPs from Exodus trackers JSON report

Tags: json, bash, linux, jq

The following command series is used to gather every bit of valuable information from [Exodus trackers](https://etip.exodus-privacy.eu.org/trackers/all). The ultimate goal would be to get this all into one `jq` statement, and if that's not possible then to just simplify as much as possible.

I'm aware of the `sub` and `gsub` functions available in `jq`, and tried to use them in the statement that parses network signatures. However, operating on the backslashes (even though they were properly escaped) didn't work, hence the `sed` cop-out.

Feedback from any angle is welcome!

<- [**JSON Input**](https://etip.exodus-privacy.eu.org/trackers/export)

*Sample:*

```json
{
  "trackers": [
    {
      "name": "ACRCloud",
      "code_signature": "com.acrcloud",
      "network_signature": "acrcloud.com|hb-minify-juc1ugur1qwqqqo4.stackpathdns.com",
      "website": "https://acrcloud.com/"
    },
    {
      "name": "ADLIB",
      "code_signature": "com.mocoplex.adlib.",
      "network_signature": "adlibr\\.com",
      "website": "https://adlibr.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "ADOP",
      "code_signature": "com.adop.sdk.",
      "network_signature": "",
      "website": "http://adop.cc/"
    },
    {
      "name": "fullstory",
      "code_signature": "com.fullstory.instrumentation.|com.fullstory.util.|com.fullstory.jni.|com.fullstory.FS|com.fullstory.rust.|com.fullstory.FSSessionData",
      "network_signature": "",
      "website": "https://www.fullstory.com/"
    }
  ]
}
```

-> [**Domain Output**](https://github.com/T145/black-mirror/releases/download/latest/exodus_domains.txt)

-> [**IP Output**](https://github.com/T145/black-mirror/releases/download/latest/exodus_ips.txt)

**exodus.bash**

```bsh
curl -s 'https://etip.exodus-privacy.eu.org/trackers/export' -o trackers.json

jq -r '.trackers[].code_signature | split("|") | reverse | .[] | split(".") | reverse | join(".") | ltrimstr(".")' trackers.json >tmp.txt
jq -r '.trackers[].network_signature | split("|") | .[]' trackers.json | sed -e 's/\\\././g' -e 's/\\//g' -e 's/^\.//' >>tmp.txt
jq -r '.trackers[].website' trackers.json | mawk -F/ '{print $3}' >>tmp.txt

gawk '/^([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/{print tolower($1)}' tmp.txt >exodus_domains.txt
gawk '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}+(\/|:|$)/{sub(/:.*/,"",$1); print $1}' tmp.txt >exodus_ips.txt

rm trackers.json
rm tmp.txt
```

Comment: Would you mind adding example inputs and outputs to the question?

Comment: @200_success Done!

Comment: Does the order of the domains/IPs in the output files matter?

Comment: @SaraJ Not particularly, though a `sort -u` couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said the order of the outputs doesn't really matter, the first `reverse` in the `.code_signature` path seems useless - as far as I can tell, all it does is change the order of certain outputs (the second `reverse` on the other hand is useful).

In `jq`, piping to `.[]` is fine, but maybe a bit awkward. `[]` can be applied on top of most simple filters, and I don't believe `split("|")[]` is any less clear than `split("|") | .[]`. But that's definitely a matter of opinion, and the `| .[]` approach is valid too.

The first of your `sed` patterns seems a bit redundant. It replaces `\\.` with `.` - so basically it removes some `\`s. But then the very next pattern removes *all* `\`s anyway, so the first one does end up seeming a bit pointless.

All you need to replicate the last two `sed` patterns in `jq` should be `replace("\\"; "") | ltrimstr(".")`. But if you *do* want that first pattern as well, `gsub("\\\\\\."; ".")` seems to work fine. Yes, that's a lot of `\`s, but each `\\` pair in a string literal represents just a single `\` in the actual string.

The `mawk` call appears to just split its input on `/` and then take the 3rd item. We can do that as well without leaving `jq` by simply doing `split("/")[2]`

If you move both the `sed` and the `mawk` into `jq`, we then have 3 `jq` commands with a common source (`trackers.json`) and a common destination (`tmp.txt`). At that point, it becomes possible to combine the three commands into one - `,` seems like a good tool for that.

Now, I'm fairly sure there are ways to do that without changing the order of the outputs, but since you said the order doesn't particularly matter, the following approach feels the most natural to me:

```
.trackers[] |
        (.code_signature | split("|")[] | split(".") | reverse | join("."))
      , (.network_signature | split ("|")[] | gsub("\\\\"; ""))
      , (.website | split("/")[2])
    | ltrimstr(".")
```

Having done that, we no longer need to save `trackers.json` - we can pipe `curl`'s output straight into `jq`:

```sh
curl -s 'https://etip.exodus-privacy.eu.org/trackers/export' |
    jq -r '.trackers[] |
          (.code_signature | split("|")[] | split(".") | reverse | join("."))
        , (.network_signature | split ("|")[] | gsub("\\\\"; ""))
        , (.website | split("/")[2])
      | ltrimstr(".")
    ' > tmp.txt
```

On a similar note, it's *also* possible to combine the `gawk`s into a single command. One possible approach might look like:

```
{ switch ($1) {
    case /^([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/:
        print tolower($1) > "exodus_domains.txt"
        break
    case /^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}+(\/|:|$)/:
        sub(/:.*/, "", $1)
        print $1 > "exodus_ips.txt"
        break
} }
```

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to get similar results, but either way, if we end up making it a single command we can then go on to pipe our `jq` straight into that. That way we can get rid of `tmp.txt` as well:

```sh
curl -s 'https://etip.exodus-privacy.eu.org/trackers/export' |
    jq -r '.trackers[] |
          (.code_signature | split("|")[] | split(".") | reverse | join("."))
        , (.network_signature | split ("|")[] | gsub("\\\\"; ""))
        , (.website | split("/")[2])
      | ltrimstr(".")
    ' |
    gawk '{ switch ($1) {
        case /^([[:alnum:]_-]{1,63}\.)+[[:alpha:]]+([[:space:]]|$)/:
            print tolower($1) > "exodus_domains.txt"
            break
        case /^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}+(\/|:|$)/:
            sub(/:.*/, "", $1)
            print $1 > "exodus_ips.txt"
            break
    } }'
```

And now we don't need to worry about creating and cleaning up temporary files, because all the action happens within a single pipeline.

Though it does get a bit unwieldy. It might be worth it at this point to break the `jq` and `awk` scripts out into separate files and do something closer to

```sh
curl -s 'https://etip.exodus-privacy.eu.org/trackers/export' |
    jq -f parse-ETIP-hosts.jq -r |
    awk -f partition-domains-and-IPs.awk \
        -v ip_file=exodus_ips.txt \
        -v domain_file=exodus_domains.txt
```

Comment: There are some edge cases I've found, but I'll ask about that in a separate post. Thanks for the help!